# Non-object when adding code into html

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in /home/gamepla3/public_html/football/result.php on line 177

The line for this is

```
<?php echo $form->error("homescore"); ?>
```

I'm failing to see how this could be the case?
The thing worked fine before I added working code into my html document so it looked better.

Now I can't get it working??

EDIT.
When the code is not within HTML, it works fine.
Once I have it within the HTML, it throws back an error?
Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Could you show more context? Where is `$form` coming from?

Comment: Seems, that `$form` is coming from nowhere ;)

Comment: $form is included within the session file which I include at the very top of the script in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump($form);
```

Well, this just require a little & simple debug logic

Confirm `$form` is a Form object, [try this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods('form');
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) 
{
  echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

does error is a defined method for Form object?

Based on your comment, the error is not a define method for object Form, so

```
$form->setError('homescore');
$errors = $form->getErrorArray(); 
// or $errors = $form->getError();
```

Comment: that returned the following, object(Form)#4 (3) { ["values"]=> array(0) { } ["errors"]=> array(0) { } ["num_errors"]=> int(0) }

Comment: I got the following when I put that in Form setValue setError value error getErrorArray

Comment: I added a $form in another part of the website and it was overwritting the other one! Dope! Sorry to waste your time :)